# Winform customize listbox item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, coding-style, custom-controls

I have a listbox that should display data that contains 2 fields: time and a message. Instead of displaying 1 line of text, I want each item to be displayed as 2 lines - 1st line is the time and the 2nd line is the message, where each line has a different style.

How can I do this? I can bind the object array to the listbox, but how do I style it? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a continuation of the earlier question; please edit the earlier one to make the specific question clearer. And btw, with the winforms listview *you can't*. Try (as already answered) WPF; you can host WPF inside winforms if needed.

Comment: This got closed as I was typing an answer.  You'll need to use the DrawMode property, there's a good example of a DrawItem event handler in the MSDN Library article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx

Comment: nobugz thanks, this looks promising :)

Comment: @nobugz - I think that's a good answer, that would do well on the *original* question.

Comment: @marc - dunno, that has something to do with data binding.

Comment: @nobugz - fine, fine... (opened)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just formally post an answer earlier left in a comment.  You'll need to use the DrawMode property, there's a good example of a DrawItem event handler in the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx).  You can draw the text any way you like, including drawing two lines of text.  Use a large Font or set the ItemHeight property with DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable to give yourself enough space for two lines.